# WinInet only downloading a part of a webpage

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wininet

I have a function that downloads a webpage into a text file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinINet.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "WinINet.lib")
void Download(wstring url)
{
    std::ofstream fout(L"temp.txt");
    HINTERNET hopen = InternetOpen(L"MyAppName",
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hopen)
    {
        DWORD flags = INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE;
        if (url.find(L"https://") == 0)
            flags |= INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;
        HINTERNET hinternet = InternetOpenUrl(hopen, url.c_str(), NULL, 0, flags, 0);
        if (hinternet)
        {
            char buf[1024];
            DWORD received = 0;
            while (InternetReadFile(hinternet, buf, sizeof(buf), &received))
            {
                if (!received) break;
                fout.write(buf, received);
            }
            InternetCloseHandle(hinternet);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hopen);
    }
    return;
}
```

when I give it "https://camelcamelcamel.com/Lodge-LMS3-Miniature-Skillet/product/B000LXA9YI" as a parameter is only outputs
https://hastebin.com/gilomexomu.xml (too big to put here)
and that cuts off most of the webpage. Im not sure if there is some anti downloading script on the website or if its simply too big.

Comment: Did InternetReadFile return any error?

Comment: no it didnt.... (its already solved btw thanks to selbie.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not your code. It's the web site.  And I believe it can only deliver gzip compressed data.  Otherwise it bombs out after a few kb of data.   curl reveals the web site is aborting the transfer prematurely:

```
$ curl https://camelcamelcamel.com/Lodge-LMS3-Miniature-Skillet/product/B000LXA9YI -o text.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15725    0 15725    0     0   4702      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--  4702
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

So I did two things to better emulate a web browser with your code

1. Put the exact same headers and user-agent as a browser.
2. Since it appears this website only wants to return gzip encoding, I had to tweak your file saving code save as binary instead of text (which causes Windows CRT to incorrectly "fix" line break chars).

Then to decode the entire HTML, I just run this from a Bash command prompt:

```
gunzip < temp.txt > temp_final.txt
```

The result is that temp_final.txt has the entire html response.

Here's the code tweaked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinINet.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "WinINet.lib")
void Download(const std::wstring& url)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("temp.txt", "wb");
    HINTERNET hopen = InternetOpen(L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36",
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hopen)
    {
        DWORD flags = INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE;
        if (url.find(L"https://") == 0)
            flags |= INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;

        LPCWSTR headers = L"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36\r\n"
L"DNT: 1\r\n"
L"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
L"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n"
L"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n";


        HINTERNET hinternet = InternetOpenUrl(hopen, url.c_str(), headers, 0, flags, 0);
        if (hinternet)
        {
            char buf[1024+1]={};
            DWORD received = 0;
            while (InternetReadFile(hinternet, buf, 1024, &received))
            {
                if (!received) break;

                printf("%d\n", received);

                fwrite(buf, 1, received, file);
            }
            InternetCloseHandle(hinternet);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hopen);
    }
    return;
}

void main()
{
    Download(L"https://camelcamelcamel.com/Lodge-LMS3-Miniature-Skillet/product/B000LXA9YI");
}
```

I tried playing around with taking out the Accept-Encoding or setting it to "identity". The result is that the server sends back half a page then aborts.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm encountering the same problem, and after research there is no winapi for GZIP/Deflate - there seems to be one after Vista, but for compatibility I'm not using it. Finally I use zlib to decompress, and it is pretty tiny and reliable.